# stop jquery effect when mouse it's stopped

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an effect start when the image it's hover and slide the different images below, but if i want the effect to stop when the mouse is stopped, what would be the best solution?

here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lzugboa/) with html - css - jQuery code

this is my example

```
    jQuery.noConflict()(function($) {

     $(document).ready(function() {
         var timeout;

         var flipImages = function($container) {
             var amount = $container.data("amount");
             var current = $container.data("current");

             if (current >= amount) {
                 current = 1;
             } else {
                 current = current + 1;
             }
             var dataAttr = "image" + current;
             var image = $container.data(dataAttr);
             $container.hide(0, function() {
                 $container.css("background-image", "url(" + image + ")");
                 $container.show(0);
                 $container.data("current", current);
             });
             timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                 flipImages($container);
             }, 1000)
         };

         $(".ct-image").hover(
             function() {
                 var $that = $(this);
                 timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                     flipImages($that);
                 }, 1000)
             },
             function() {
                 if (timeout) {
                     clearTimeout(timeout);
                 }
             });
     });
 });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the mouse is stopped"? Do you mean when the mouse is moved out? Also, what happens (or not) with your code? Do you get any console errors?

Comment: maybe with this function .stop()  ?

Comment: i want active the effect only if' i move the mouse on my image, so when i hover a image and don't move the mouse i want the effect it's stopped

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'mousemove' event with jQuery

```
$('.ct-image').mousemove(function(){
  //your code here
});
```

Here 'mousemove' event will trigger only when you are moving your mouse on the image. If you stop moving, no event triggered.

You can check the doc here: https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Cheers

Comment: if i use .mousemove the event not trigger.

Comment: Can you put your whole code (html + css +  js) in a jsfiddle ? I'll take a look :)